# How to avoid "Limit of total fields exceeded" error in metricbeat in conjunction with the prometheus module?

Tags: elasticsearch, prometheus, metricbeat

I'm running metricbeat in kubernetes using the helm chart from helm.elastic.co.
This results in metricbeat loading a huge index template with 3776 fields into the elasticsearch index.
But only 633 are actually used and having values sent to the index.

The problem is, that I get the following error, when the metricbeat-metricbeat-metrics pod is trying to send events to elasticsearch:

```
Cannot index event ..."reason":"Limit of total fields [5000] has been exceeded"}
```

This error occurs in a metricbeat instance, where the prometheus module with a "collector" metricset is used.
I'm not sure, if the loaded template is the reason, or if the events being forwarded from prometheus actually contain more than 5000 fields each.

Nevertheless:
Is it common practice to have such big templates being loaded by elasticsearch?
And if not: what is the way to limit the template to the fields actually being used?

**Edit:**

Further analysis lead to the conclusion, that the size of the elasticsearch template is not causing this error:
The indexing error occurs only, when the prometheus module in metricbeat is active. The template size keeps the same in this case.

The prometheus should scrape the metrics from the running pods.
The number of metrics was originally:

- 61274 metrics at all (`{__name__!=""}`)
- 956 different metric names. ( `group by(__name__) ({__name__!=""}`)

I changed the scrape settings of prometheus, which resulted in:

- 118 metrics at all (`{__name__!=""}`)
- 55 different metric names. ( `group by(__name__) ({__name__!=""}`)

metricbeat's prometheus module is configured as:

```yaml
      - module: prometheus
        period: 30s
        metricsets: ["collector"]
        hosts: ["prometheus-server"]
        metrics_path: '/federate'
        query:
          'match[]': '{job="kubernetes-pods"}'
        processors:
        - add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

Where that query `{job="kubernetes-pods"}` results in exactly that 118 series.

But: The `Cannot index event ...` error still occurs!

Here is the complete error log line:

```
2021-12-03T07:15:07.227Z    WARN    [elasticsearch] elasticsearch/client.go:408 Cannot index event publisher.Event{Content:beat.Event{Timestamp:time.Time{wall:0xc0628ede3b502221, ext:907213012182, loc:(*time.Location)(0x5862e80)}, Meta:null, Fields:{"agent":{"ephemeral_id":"e7ef097d-95c8-4f60-a63f-0de436c45195","hostname":"metricbeat-metricbeat-metrics-59c8d8b865-b2gqc","id":"2c17c983-631e-4f70-ab36-a56bc1b5b254","name":"metricbeat-metricbeat-metrics-59c8d8b865-b2gqc","type":"metricbeat","version":"7.10.0"},"cloud":{"account":{"id":"xxxx"},"availability_zone":"eu-central-1b","image":{"id":"ami-xxxx"},"instance":{"id":"i-xxxx"},"machine":{"type":"t3a.xlarge"},"provider":"aws","region":"eu-central-1"},"ecs":{"version":"1.6.0"},"event":{"dataset":"prometheus.collector","duration":5888251,"module":"prometheus"},"host":{"name":"metricbeat-metricbeat-metrics-59c8d8b865-b2gqc"},"metricset":{"name":"collector","period":30000},"prometheus":{"labels":{"app_kubernetes_io_instance":"...","app_kubernetes_io_name":"my-pod-name","instance":"10.124.2.235:8080","job":"kubernetes-pods","kubernetes_namespace":"mynamespace","kubernetes_pod_name":"my-pod-85746d8c4f-wb4kq","name":"rabbit","pod_template_hash":"85746d8c4f"},"metrics":{"rabbitmq_acknowledged_published_total":0.000000,"rabbitmq_acknowledged_total":9.000000,"rabbitmq_channels":2.000000,"rabbitmq_connections":1.000000,"rabbitmq_consumed_total":9.000000,"rabbitmq_failed_to_publish_total":0.000000,"rabbitmq_not_acknowledged_published_total":0.000000,"rabbitmq_published_total":0.000000,"rabbitmq_rejected_total":0.000000,"rabbitmq_unrouted_published_total":0.000000}},"service":{"address":"http://prometheus-server/federate?match%5B%5D=%7Bjob%3D%22kubernetes-pods%22%7D","type":"prometheus"}}, Private:interface {}(nil), TimeSeries:true}, Flags:0x0, Cache:publisher.EventCache{m:common.MapStr(nil)}} (status=400): {"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Limit of total fields [5000] has been exceeded"}
```

Using the query api instead of federation causes the same error:

```
      - module: prometheus
        period: 30s
        metricsets: ["collector"]
        hosts: ["prometheus-server"]
        metrics_path: /metrics
        metrics_filters:
          include: [".+"]
```

Only when I specify a include pattern, which matches some of the metrics - like "jvm.*" - the error disappears.
But I definitely do **not** want to explicitly include all of my metrics within the metricbeat config.

Comment: 3776 fields definitely is a lot. Did you try [overriding the template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-template.html)?

Comment: no. but it turned out, that the template size actually is not causing this error. The error occurs only, when forwarding events from the prometheus server. 

When prometheus is disabled, the template size is the same, but the error is gone.

Comment: How many metrics do you have exposed in Prometheus? Incorrect setup (for example, creating a new metric for each customer instead of using tags) might cause metric explosion which will affect Elasticsearch as well.

Comment: the prometheus server has a very limited set of metrics. A query for `group by(__name__) ({__name__ != ""})` within the prometheus gui returns only 55 series.

Comment: I changed the metricbeat setting to use the query api instead of federation ( as recommended by [metricbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-metricset-prometheus-collector.html#_scraping_all_metrics_from_a_prometheus_server): 
This results in the same error.
No error, when I use pattern e.g. `"jvm.*"` in the include clause (19 series matching)

Comment: How many fields do you have is Elasticsearch mapping when using `"jvm.*"`?

Comment: I do not know how to check that at the metricbeat or elastisearch side. But here are the results of queries inside the prometheus gui: `{__name__ =~"^jvm.*"}`: 54 result series and `group by(__name__) ({__name__ =~"^jvm.*"})` results in 19 series at all (for the whole prometheus server)

Comment: Run it with `"jvm.*"` as a filter (so that indexing succeeds) then [retrieve ES mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) and estimate how many fields does it have.

Comment: Doing a `GET /metricbeat-7.12.1-2021.12.07/_mapping` and counting the number of times, the word "type" is found in the resulting json:  `3229`. The only metricbeat instance writing to this index has only one module configured: `prometheus` with `metrics_path: '/federate'` and `query: 'match[]': '{__name__=~"^jvm.*"}'`. so it seems, that metricbeat creates an index template with all the fields it knows about, regardless whether those metrics are scraped at all.

Comment: The number of fields actually written to the index is very low in comparison: When I don't create an index template at all and rely on dynamic indexing and then create an Index pattern in the kibana GUI, the number of fields shown there is around 300.

Comment: Yeah that's definitely weird. Sorry I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by increasing the `index.mapping.total_fields.limit` to 10000.

The error only goes away, as soon as metricbeat is able to apply the new index template. That means, I needed to delete the current index, where metricbeat appends the docs and to restart the metricbeat process.

This is not really satisfying.
But I as far as I know, most users simply live with the slightly large default index templates without having any problems.